# Find the maximum output over a variable-length period

Tags: python, sql, sas

I have a hypothetical set of data with 3 columns that has monthly profit data for a set of widget machines.  I am trying to figure out the maximum profit period within a 2-year span.

The 3 columns are as follows:
**name**: identifier of widget machine (there are maybe 100 of these)
**date**: month/year over a 2 year period
**profit**: dollars made from widgets that month (can be negative if costs exceed revenue)

The *maximum profit period* is a concurrent set of months at least 3 months long (and could encompass all of the data).

Obviously I could brute force this and simply test every combination: Jan-Mar, Jan-Apr, Jan-May, Feb-Apr, etc. but I am looking for a better solution than creating all of these by hand.  It seems like the data is a bit too big to want to transpose across and turn months into columns so I would like to be able to operate on a stacked dataset as described.

I'd prefer a sas data step but an sql query that works in proc SQL would be fine as well (but the sets of subqueries that might be required are beyond my ability).

**Example Data:**

```
data max(drop=dt);
 length name dt $50;
 infile datalines delimiter=','; 
 input name $ dt profit;
 date=input(dt,mmddyy10.);
 format date mmddyy10.;
 datalines;                      
  Widget1,01/01/2011,1000
  Widget1,02/01/2011,2000
  Widget1,03/01/2011,500
  Widget2,01/01/2011,100
  Widget2,02/01/2011,200
  Widget2,03/01/2011,-50
  Widget2,04/01/2011,250
  Widget2,05/01/2011,-150
  Widget2,06/01/2011,-250
  Widget2,07/01/2011,400
  Widget2,08/01/2011,0
  Widget2,03/01/2011,-200
;
```

Maybe a better phrasing of the question would be "How do I come up with all possible consecutive combinations of values?"  From a query like that, I could then take the max of combinations where # of values >= 3.

The query would build up every combination of sequential rows in the table, drop those where there are less than 3 rows, and then return the max value (grouped by Widget# of course). I suppose it would also helpful to know the starting and ending row for each combination.  I'm trying to work out how this would be done in an SQL query (doesn't sound like a sas datastep to my mind)

**Python Sample:**
Here is a sample with some made up data that I wrote in Python.  It is not the most efficient thing but it gets the sort of result I am looking for--I just can't figure out how to replicate it in SQL or SAS:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = []
data.append(['Widget1','Jan',5])
data.append(['Widget1','Feb',1])
data.append(['Widget1','Mar',-2])
data.append(['Widget1','Apr',0])
data.append(['Widget1','May',-3])
data.append(['Widget1','Jun',8])
data.append(['Widget1','Jul',-2])
data.append(['Widget1','Aug',1])
data.append(['Widget2','Jan',-1])
data.append(['Widget2','Feb',1])
data.append(['Widget2','Mar',-3])
data.append(['Widget2','Apr',1])
data.append(['Widget2','May',-60])
data.append(['Widget2','Jun',9])
data.append(['Widget2','Jul',-2])
data.append(['Widget2','Aug',20])

results = []
for key, group in groupby(data, lambda g: g[0]):
    max = -999999
    for i,v in enumerate(data):
        if key <> v[0]:
            continue
        runningtotal = 0
        for j,w in enumerate(data):
            if key <> w[0]:
                continue
            if i <= j:
                runningtotal = runningtotal + w[2]
            if i+2 <= j and runningtotal > max:
                max = runningtotal
                maxstart = v[1]
                maxend = w[1]           
    results.append([key, maxstart, maxend, max])
print results
```

This gives me the result of 
[['Widget1', 'Jan', 'Jun', 9], 
['Widget2', 'Jun', 'Aug', 27]]
for the fake python data I made.

Comment: Which database (Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL etc.) are you using? (Date arithmetic functions/operators vary between platforms, so this will affect the answer.) Also, is the date field populated with the first, last, median or random day of the month?

Comment: I'm using a sas dataset with proc SQL (in my experience it behaves pretty close to mysql...there are differences but most SQL queries work fine).  Date field has the first day of the month.

Comment: I added the beginning of some sample data...could you adjust to make it more accurate. Also, if you could use the sample to point out an example result. This goes a long way toward helping us help you.

Comment: I extended the data for widget2.  The example result here would be from 1/2011 to 4/2011 which produces the 4 months with the largest value(500).  If you extended it out further, you would include negative months which would cut down the total.  If you total up all months, you only get 300. If you took only 3 months (like 2/11 to 4/11) you would be discarding a positive amount.

Comment: @otto: The intervals 1/2011 to 7/2011 and 1/2011 to 8/2011 also sum to 500.  What's the right answer?

Comment: Sorry, bad fake data design on my part.  In this situation, it doesn't really matter as long as we know that the maximum consecutive group is 500 but I suppose the preference would be for the shortest interval when there is a tie.

Comment: I wrote an example in Python with some more made up data that seems to do a version of what I want.  It might not be the most efficient, but it outputs the results--I just don't know how to make a SQL query or SAS data step that does the same thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have a working method here.  A combination of a proc SQL cross join and a quick data step seems to give everything I want (though it could probably be done in a single big SQL query).  Here it is on the sample data from my python example.

```
data one;
 length name $50;
 infile datalines delimiter=','; 
 input name $ dt profit;
 datalines;                      
  Widget1,1,5
  Widget1,2,1
  Widget1,3,-2
  Widget1,4,0
  Widget1,5,-3
  Widget1,6,8
  Widget1,7,-2
  Widget1,8,1
  Widget2,1,-1
  Widget2,2,1
  Widget2,3,-3
  Widget2,4,1
  Widget2,5,-60
  Widget2,6,9
  Widget2,7,-2
  Widget2,8,20
;

proc sql;
create table two as
  select a.name, a.dt as start, b.dt as end, b.profit
    from one as a cross join one as b
    where start <= end and a.name = b.name
  order by name, start, end;
quit;
run;

data two; set two;
  by name start;
  if first.start then sum=0;
  sum+profit;
  months = (end-start)+1;
run;

proc means noprint data=two(where=(months>=3));
  by name;
  output out=three(drop=_:) maxid(sum(start) sum(end))=start end max(sum)=;
run;
```

Making it operate on date constructs instead of numbered months would be trivial (just change the 'months' variable to be based on actual dates).

Answer (score 1):

Your core problem appears to be that you see combinatorially many periods, but you want a solution that doesn't require a combinatorial amount of work.

Luckily for you, if you have N months, you can solve this problem in O(N^2) time with O(N) space.

The trick is that you don't actually need to save all the period's values; you only need the maximal one. So let's break the big problem down into smaller chunks.

First, create two arrays of length N and fill them with zeroes. Now, you read in the first month and (if it earned a profit) put it in the first cell of each - it's the "best run of length 1" and also the "current run of length 1". If it's negative, leave the "best" at zero, but fill the "current" cell anyhow.

Next you read in the second month. If the second month earned more profit than the first, you replace the first cell of each array with the value of the second month (otherwise just replace the "current" one but leave the "best" alone). Then, if the first month plus the second month nets positive, put that value in the second cell of each - that's the "longest run of length 2" and the "current run of length 2" - the current-run-of-two plus the most recent cell is the current-run-of-three.

When you read in the third month, things start to get interesting. First you check the first cell - if the third month is greater than the value currently there, replace it. Next you check the second cell. If adding the third month *and subtracting the first* would make that value greater, do it. Otherwise just put it in the "current" array, but not the "best" array. Finally, populate the third cells with the "current run of length 2" value plus the third cell.

Continue on in this fashion. When you reach row i, you have the current runs having length 1..i stored, along with the best of each length so far.

When you reach the end of the array, you can discard the "current" values and just take the max of the "best" array!

Because this requires 1+2+3+...+N operations, it's O(N^2). Only one pass through the input data is necessary, and the storage is 2N, which is O(N). If you wish to know *which* period was most profitable, just store the cell that begins the run as well as the run's sum.

Comment: Interesting.  I'm not sure that this would be easy to code in SAS but this does appear to be the most efficient solution.  The problem is that arrays in SAS seem so goofy to me and I think this would require me to know how many months of data there were (on each individual run I will know, but I would have to change the code between runs).  I think I could implement it with some do loops and N-back lag() functions but it sounds really messy in SAS.  I have come up with a SQL based solution that is functional but not efficient --I am a new user so I have to wait another 45 minutes to post it

Answer (score 0):

The data step (and Proc SQL) will read the data sequentially, however to mimic some of the functionality of the array solution from other programming languages, you can use the [LAG](http://support.sas.com/kb/25/938.html) function to look at previous observations.

If you sort your data by NAME and DATE, then you can use the [BY statement in your data step](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000761931.htm)  and have access to FIRST. and LAST. to know when the NAME has changed.

Once you work out the algorithm, which obviously is the hardest part and which I don't have yet, you can OUTPUT each profit total per date sequence, then sort the new data set by name and profit total which should put the highest total at the beginning of the BY group (First.Name).

Maybe this will spur some additional ideas from you or other SAS programmers.

Comment: Thanks, I have a sample code that I think works off of an SQL cross join (at least for my purposes, for more than a few hundred line data sets, it might be too inefficient)  I'll post it as soon as the 8-hour self-answer limit for new users expires.